# change color of nth child with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), its structure is like this:

```
<div class="slick-track">
  <ul>
    <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
    <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
    <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
    <li class="slick"></li>
    <li class="slick"></li>
    <li class="slick"></li>
    <li class="slick"></li>
    <li class="slick"></li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

It shows 3 slides at a time. i.e. when next slide shown 2,3,4 `li` gets `slick-active` class

What I want to do is select middle element from the active and change its background color.

I have tried doing this but it doesn't work

```
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}

.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(even) {
    background: green;
}
```

**OR**

```
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

it counts all the `li` and then select even off betn them

**EDIT**
when next slide comes visible html looks like this

Here is the problem `.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(odd)` if use this it selects the **odd** `li`  in all the li elements

```
<div class="slick-track">
      <ul>
        <li class="slick"></li>
        <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
        <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
        <li class="slick slick-active"></li>
        <li class="slick"></li>
        <li class="slick"></li>
        <li class="slick"></li>
        <li class="slick"></li>
       <ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` prefix for `slick-active`. It should be `.slick-track .slick-active:...`

Comment: sorry typo mistake

Comment: Shouldn't `<li>` elements be within a `<ul>` or `<ol>`?

Comment: Looks ok over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/8t75vncy/

Comment: it working. no issue?

Comment: @harsh Phil it is working fine.... `it counts all the li and then select even off betn them` It dont selects middle element when next li comes visible in slide

Comment: @parish so what **exactly** does the HTML look like *"when next li comes visible in slide"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active {
    background-color: initial;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(even){
    background: red;
}
```

This is for all numbers like 2,4,6,... For your case, you need 2.

You can also use just:

```
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(2){
    background: red;
}
```

In nth-child, n starts from 0 and selected elements starts from 1.

Comment: yes tried first one but when next slide is shown the 1st and 3rd  active-class gets red background

Comment: Try :nth-child(even)

Comment: Ah yes, now got your problem. It happens because the nth-child selector counts siblings (i.e., elements having the same parent), but apply style on elements it self.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `.` for class `slick-active`

```
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(2){
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see that while I was answering

Answer (score 1):

**.slick-track slick-active:nth-child(odd)** means select an odd element of type **slick-active** which is inside class **slick-track** .but here you need to select the class named **slick-active** .So you need to include a **"."** at the start of the name.Here is the modified css:

```
    .slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(odd){
       background: red;
      }

     .slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(even){
        background: green;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You skiped the `.` for class repesentation .
 so use below style

```
<style> 
.slick-track  .slick-active:nth-child(odd){
    background: red;
}

.slick-track  .slick-active:nth-child(even){
    background: green;
}
</style>
```

OR 
   you can use Jquery

```
   <script>
   $( "div li:nth-child(even)" ).css('background','green');
   $( "div li:nth-child(odd)" ).css('background','red');
   </script>
```

Comment: Ok !!  Very late .

Answer (score 0):

Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Here, we specify a background color for all li elements whose index is a multiple of 2:

```css
.slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(2n+1){
       background: orange;
      }

     .slick-track .slick-active:nth-child(2n+2){
        background: black;
      }
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
<ul>
<li class="slick">slick</li>
<li class="slick slick-active">slick-active</li>
<li class="slick slick-active">slick-active</li>
<li class="slick slick-active">slick-active</li>
<li class="slick">slick</li>
<li class="slick">slick</li>
<li class="slick">slick</li>
<li class="slick">slick</li>
</ul>
</div>
```